# Duplicate campaign parameters error

Tags: google-analytics

We have two views on a property with similar configuration.

I have this error message on analytics, and I will like to know if I have to delete one. The property views are the same, but one have http and the other have the https.

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies the problem lies in your campaign parameters. This error signifies that your marketing campaigns leading to your site are not tagged the 'proper way' that means that there might be two advertising campaigns that have the same utm_campaign parameter or the same but with different casing. The solution is to go at your reporting interface under Aquisition -> Campaigns -> All Campaigns and check your campaign names. If this is the case you can be more consistent with your campaign naming process or follow [this guide](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/01/08/fix-google-analytics-notifications/) that gives some more advanced options based on view filtering and so on.